# Is OutputProjectionWrapper same as BasicDecoder's output_layer?

Tags: tensorflow

In `tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder` document, it says `output_layer: (Optional)` An instance of `tf.layers.Layer`, i.e., `tf.layers.Dense`. Optional layer to apply to the RNN output prior to storing the result or sampling.

In `tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper` is Operator adding an output projection to the given cell

I assume these are same?